# How to put localdatetime as array of values in java

Tags: java, json, localdatetime

I am trying to form a string something like this using the below function:

```
{"orderId":123,"eventName":"C","messageTs":[2022,2,15,7,51,2,653189800]}

private String generateMessage(Integer orderId, String eventName) throws JSONException, IOException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("eventName", eventName);
    json.put("orderId", orderId);
    json.put("messageTs", LocalDateTime.now()); 
    return json.toString();
  }
```

but my above function is giving me the output

```
 {"orderId":1198,"eventName":"C","messageTs":"2022-02-15T07:51:02.653189800"}
```

what to change in my function so that my messagets looks like array of some values

Comment: That has to be the most ill-devised timestamp format I've seen in a while. Using such an unstandard format inside JSON is amazingly poor design.

Answer (score 1):

The `json.put()` function just adds the `LocalDateTime` object to the `HashMap` of the JSON object. It will not perform any formatting to your `LocalDateTime` object. And when you call `toString()`, the date object will also use `toString()`. The library that you are using is very useful and customizable, but [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) can provide you with different formats and customizations.

Secondly, the format that you want to use (an array) is a very weird format that is not recommended. If you really want to do that, then create a function that does that for you:

```java
public int[] dateToArray(LocalDateTime localDateTime)
{
    int year = localDateTime.getYear();
    int month = localDateTime.getMonthValue();
    int day = localDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
    int h = localDateTime.getHour();
    int m = localDateTime.getMinute();
    int s = localDateTime.getSecond();
    int sx = localDateTime.getNano();

    return new int[]{year, month, day, h, m, s, sx};
}
```